# HTML - DIV element ruining couple DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have very annoying problem with my HTML code. Demo: http://eclipzh.exg.lv/itap/ , as you see, adding #news-bg divider, it ruins #users-online and #adverts element which are in one global #menu divider. HTML5+CSS3 platform, recommends look the site with Chrome/FF, IE for while is not supported so far. Thanks!

HTML+CSS:http://paste.laravel.com/KIi html and css is in one textcode, cause of reputation limit.

- Bad

Comment: Please post some relevant html & css

Comment: I don't think your reputation can limit your ability of posting code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `#menu` you could set `position: absolute;`.